# Не работает редирект в yii2

Tags: yii2

Задача следующая. 
Перед любым контроллером проверить, есть ли кука, если нет, то сделать редирект.

Создал компонент BeforeController:

```
class BeforeController extends Component
{    
    public function init()
    {
        if(substr_count(Yii::$app->request->url, 'auth/login'))
            return parent::init();

        if(!isset($_COOKIE["auth_cookie"])){
            Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(['auth/login']);
        }
        return parent::init();
    }
}
```

Описал его в конфиге:

```
'components' => [
    'BeforeController'=>[
        'class'=>'app\components\BeforeController'
    ],
...
]
```

Добавил в секцию bootstrap:

```
'bootstrap' => ['log', 'BeforeController'],
```

Куки нет, переадресация не работает. В чем может быть дело?

Пробовал вставлять этот код в контроллер, там работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего редирект происходит только в тот момент когда объект `response` возвращается экшном. При инициализации компонентов из `bootstrap` в `response` прописывается свойство куда редиректить, но потом перед экшеном `response` заново инициализируется. Надо исходники смотреть, чтобы понять как оно работает. В любом случае что-то делать с `response` имеет смысл только внутри `action`.

В Yii2 есть готовый класс для подобных задач ограничения доступа - `AccessControl` (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-filters), в методе matchCallback можно задавать любые проверки. Для контроллера можно как-то так:

```
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'except' => ['auth/login'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                            return isset(Yii::$app->request->cookies['auth_cookie']);
                        }
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Либо для всех контроллеров в конфиге приложения (как указано здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067849/yii2-require-all-controller-and-action-to-login) после `components` добавляем:

```
'as access' => [
    'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
    'except' => ['auth/login'],
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                return isset(Yii::$app->request->cookies['auth_cookie']);
            }
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: Все хорошо, только почему-то Yii::$app->request->cookies['auth_cookie'] не срабатывает, а $_COOKIE['auth_cookie'] работает.

Answer (score 2):

Создаете новый контроллер, наследуете его от базового Controller-а, а остальные контроллеры, в которых нужно осуществлять проверку - наследуете от только что созданного контроллера, в котором следует определить метод beforeAction в котором и выполнить все необходимые проверки

Comment: не совсем люблю наследоваться от общего контроллера, потому что может возникнуть потребность какому-нибудь контроллеру отнаследоваться от контроллера какой-то библиотеки (из папки vendor).

Comment: Попробуйте через трейт в таком случае